# Wired unmanaged after playing with VPN

Tags: network-manager, vpn

I was trying to install VPN server and followed some 'tutorials' and now I end up with eth0 - unmanaged.

when called 'network-admin' there is no tab 'connection' just General,DNS,Hosts. WiFi works fine, but cable looks dead. It says 'Wired unmanaged' and no option to reset or ad new connection or any 'manage' option.

Comment: Found it!
"To resolve this, all you need is to remove all other interface except lo from /etc/network/interfaces
sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces #working config
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces #previous non-working config
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

Once you are done with necessary changes, restart netwok-manager
sudo service network-manager restart"

AFTER: http://www.linuxreaders.com/2011/12/02/ubuntu-unmanaged-interface-after-pxe-installation/

Thanks anyway :)

Pifon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During your tutorial-following, you have probably added a definition for `eth0` in `/etc/network/interfaces`. If an interface is defined in this file, Network Manager assumes that you want to control it manually, and so doesn't manage it for you.

If this is indeed the problem, you can fix it by reverting `/etc/network/interfaces` to its default. It should look something like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

-- importantly, not containing any stanzas for `eth0`.